# substituting NAN region in meshgride in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wrote below code to show a vector field:

```
clear all;
close all;
phi = 90;
[x,y] = meshgrid(-3:0.1:3,-3:0.1:3);
u = (x.*(-1+3.*(x.*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./(x.^2+y.^2))./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2))+...
    ((x-2).*(-1+3.*((x-2).*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./((x-2).^2+y.^2))./((x-2).^2+y.^2).^(3/2))+...
    ((x+2).*(-1+3.*((x+2).*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./((x+2).^2+y.^2))./((x+2).^2+y.^2).^(3/2));
v = (y.*(-1+3.*(x.*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./(x.^2+y.^2))./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2))+...
    (y.*(-1+3.*((x-2).*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./((x-2).^2+y.^2))./((x-2).^2+y.^2).^(3/2))+...
    (y.*(-1+3.*((x+2).*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./((x+2).^2+y.^2))./((x+2).^2+y.^2).^(3/2));
h = streamslice(x,y,u,v,0.5);
```

The problem is, there are three points in space in which `u` and `v` becomes infinite: `(y=0,x=0)`, `(y=0,x=-2)` and `(y=0,x=2)`. As `v` and `u` become infinite, there is no vector field in that region and output is an empty region. I want MATLAB to omit infinite part of `v` and `u` and plot other parts of `v` and `u`. For example at `(y=0,x=0)`, I want to show vector field below (which is not infinite):

```
u = ((x-2).*(-1+3.*((x-2).*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./((x-2).^2+y.^2))./((x-2).^2+y.^2).^(3/2))+...
    ((x+2).*(-1+3.*((x+2).*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./((x+2).^2+y.^2))./((x+2).^2+y.^2).^(3/2));
v = (y.*(-1+3.*((x-2).*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./((x-2).^2+y.^2))./((x-2).^2+y.^2).^(3/2))+...
    (y.*(-1+3.*((x+2).*cosd(phi)+y.*sind(phi)).^2./((x+2).^2+y.^2))./((x+2).^2+y.^2).^(3/2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index in order to replace only the non finite value:

```
u = [1 1 inf NaN 1 1];
v = [1 1 inf NaN 1 1];

u1 = [2 2 2 2 2 2];
v1 = [2 2 2 2 2 2];

%Now, if an element of u or v is not finite it is replaced by the same value of the matrices u1,v1.

u(~isfinite(u))=u1(~isfinite(u));
v(~isfinite(v))=v1(~isfinite(v));
```

Second option:

you can also interpolate the non finite value with `griddata`:

```
finite     = isfinite(u) & isfinite(v);
u = griddata(x(finite), y(finite), u(finite), x, y);
v = griddata(x(finite), y(finite), v(finite), x, y);
```

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]